# Should event registered with RegisterOcclusionStatusEvent be unregistered before DXGI factory destruction?

Tags: c++, winapi, directx, dxgi

I'm registering occlusion event that I've created by calling `IDXGIFactory2::RegisterOcclusionStatusEvent`. This method gives me a cookie that I *can* later pass to `IDXGIFactory2::UnregisterOcclusionStatus`. I'm assuming that I'm still holding an ownership of this event handle and later close it after destroying DXGI factory. But is it actually safe to ignore the cookie and destroy the factory without unregistering event?

Comment: this is depended of implementation `IDXGIFactory2`. faster of all `RegisterOcclusionStatusEvent` allocate something like `std::pair` - `<dwCookie, hEvent>` and insert it in some container. this entry is removed and deallocated when you call `UnregisterOcclusionStatus`. also in destructor this container probably will be destroyed and all still existing entries will be freed anyway. but not need rely on this guessing. need direct call `UnregisterOcclusionStatus` how minimum/usual before call `Release` on this interface. if you save pointer to interface, in what problem save `dwCookie` too ?

Comment: Supposed problems vary from factory instance leak (excessive reference and extended lifetime) to internal use of event handle when it's no longer valid (or, a leak of duplicated event handle). While all mentioned don't seem fatal, not unregistering is not going to give any severe problems. Because documentation does not document the behavior exactly (such as "caller must unregister..." etc) and behavior actually may change, the I think safest is to unregister and not think of possible side issues of doing otherwise.

Comment: The confusion also comes from the ownership pattern that is opposite of what `IDXGISwapChain2::GetFrameLatencyWaitableObject` provides. It doesn't make much sense that we need to bother so much with manual creation / registration / unregistration of event.

Comment: `GetFrameLatencyWaitableObject` return to you event handle. you become owner of this handle and need close it, when no longer need. when `RegisterOcclusionStatusEvent`  simply save *your* event handle and use. it assume that handle will be valid until you not call `UnregisterOcclusionStatus`. in all case absolute safe call `UnregisterOcclusionStatus` at any time *before* you close own event

Comment: [Documentation for `GetFrameLatencyWaitableObject`](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/DirectXLatency-sample-a2e2c9c3) doesn't say that returned handle must be later closed, and they don't close it in [DirectX latency sample](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/DirectXLatency-sample-a2e2c9c3) either.

Comment: yes documentation not say, but this handle *must* be closed, this is very clear from view code of *GetFrameLatencyWaitableObject* - it call *DuplicateHandle* on some object and return to you duplicated handle. nobody more have this handle. so if you not close it - will be resource leak, until process not terminated

Comment: so sample is wrong in this place - it must close *m_frameLatencyWaitableObject*

Comment: Yeah, turns out that `GetFrameLatencyWaitableObject` returns different handle  every time so they definitely must be manually closed later.

Comment: look for [implementation](http://i.imgur.com/aYZfs7w.png) - *GetFrameLatencyWaitableObject* call `HANDLE TargetHandle;
DuplicateHandle(GetCurrentProcess(), m_238h, GetCurrentProcess(), &TargetHandle, SYNCHRONIZE, TRUE, 0);
return TargetHandle;` - so it simply duplicate own handle and return tou duplicated. nobody more have this handle after function return - so if you not close it yourself - nobody close it, because nobody have it value. more exactly kernel close it when process terminated